# Android Studio Debugger: switch between C and Java stack?

Tags: android-studio, debugging

I write a lot of C++ NDK code for my app and debugging is working fine with Android Studio with one exception. If the debugger break in C++ code i can view the stackframes of the native C stack but when i go up stackframes once i reach the point where the JNI call is made i see the java virtuam machine implementation frames and not the Java frames that invoked the JNI call.

Is there any way i can switch between the two stack views?